# how to test a facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook, iframe, dreamweaver, fbml

I am developing a facebook application using php5. I am using dreamweaver as the editor. I want to test the application. I have a test account. But, now, how do I test the application using that test account? Do I need to submit my application prior to testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to submit your application to the directory.

You should make your application usable only by the developers, and then add all the testers as developers of the app.

Be aware though that the developers / testers can see things like your API key, so trust is important.

What this means is that normal users cannot stumble across your application and break things (or be broken).

There are also limits on requests, notifications, etc.

This is a little hazy because it was a fair while ago, and also bear in mind that things have changed a lot since then.